# Opencv in memory Mat representation

Tags: c++, opencv

I know that in memory opencv represents Mat objects as one big array. So if I have 3 channels mat of dimension 200x200 then In memory it will store this mat in an array of size 3x200x200. Or more generally any Mat in memory will be stored as `channels*rows*cols`. We can get such array as

```
double *array = (double)mat.data;
```

assuming that matrix is of type double

Now my question is what is the way to index this array for instance if I want to access element at channel ch, row r and col c is following is valid indexing

```
array[ch*rows*cols + c * rows + r]
```

or

```
array[ch*rows*cols + r * cols + c]
```

Regards
Ahsan

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you can see in the data layout reported on the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat),  you can access the values like:

```
for(int r=0; r<rows; ++r){
    for(int c=0; c<cols; ++c){
        for(int ch=0; ch<nchannels; ++ch){
            double val = array[(nchannels*mat.step*r) + (nchannels*c) + ch];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's `mat.step`? I haven't found the definition of it from the docs.

Comment: @Raining look at the "Detailed Description" of the Mat object: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html

Comment: It just described how it's used, but I'm still confused and searching more clear explanation now.

Comment: @Rainning See the explanation for the optional `step` argument of the `Mat()` [constructor](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a): "_Number of bytes each matrix row occupies. The value should include the padding bytes at the end of each row, if any. If the parameter is missing (set to AUTO_STEP ), no padding is assumed and the actual step is calculated as cols*elemSize(). See Mat::elemSize._". So in this case: `cols * sizeof(double)` (assuming the no padding default).

Answer (score 1):

You can get values in array like this:

```
double val = array+ (r*mat.step)+c*mat.channels()+ch;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found other answers a bit confusing: `mat.step` is the size of a row in bytes, not in (double) elements, and it does already take into consideration the number of channels. To access val you should use:

```
double* array = (double*) mat.data; // was (double) mat.data in the question
double value = array[ ((mat.step)/mat.elemSize1())*c+mat.channels()*r+ch]; // (mat.step)/mat.elemSize1() is the actual row length in (double) elements
```

You can verify this and other approaches comparing them with the `.at<>` operator as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
const int w0=5;
const int h=3;
const int w=4;
double data[w0*h*3];
for (int y=0; y<h; y++)
    for (int x=0; x<w0; x++)
        for (int ch=0; ch<3; ch++)
            data[3*(x+w0*y)+ch]=1000+100*(y)+10*(x)+ch;

Mat m0(h,w0,CV_64FC3, data);
Rect roi(0,0,w,h);
Mat mat=m0(roi);

int c=3, r=2, ch=1;
Vec3d v = mat.at<Vec3d>(r,c);
cout<<"the 3 channels at row="<<r<<", col="<<c<<": "<<v<<endl;
double* array= (double*) mat.data;
double expect = 1000+100*r+10*c+ch;
double value= array[ ((mat.step)/mat.elemSize1())*r+mat.channels()*c+ch];
cout<<"row="<<r<<", col="<<c<<", ch="<<ch<<": expect="<<expect<<", value="<<value<<endl;
return  0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this [official link](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/da5/tutorial_how_to_scan_images.html) will help you!

For RGB type image:

[image: RGB image in memory]